# Formula to validate the column is not empty if a column contain a particular value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, validation, column-validation

I need to add a column validation to my list.

I have 4 columns.

1. Status (Choice)
2. Version
3. OutCome (Choice)
4. Effort

If I choose Status as 'Completed', The other fields should not be blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the validation formula like below in list validation settings (not column validation settings):

```
=IF([Status] = "Completed", IF(OR(ISBLANK([Version]), ISBLANK([OutCome]), ISBLANK([Effort])), false, true), true)
```

You have to add this formula under **List Validation** settings.

Follow below steps:

1. Go to SharePoint list
2. Click on **Settings** icon and select **List settings**
3. Select **Validation settings**
4. Add formula & user message and click **Save**

Comment: Thank you ! It's worked with text field but not with choice field. Actually **OutCome** is a choice field which have 3 values like 'A','B' and 'C'.